# Can you freeze yogurt

Tags: freezing, yogurt

Can you freeze yogurt? It was on sale, and I am going to use it to make smoothies.

Comment: There is a desert in the (UK at least) called "frozen yogurt" :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, yoghurt can be frozen - according to [this Canadian government agency](http://healthycanadians.gc.ca/eating-nutrition/healthy-eating-saine-alimentation/safety-salubrite/tips-conseils/storage-entreposage-eng.php), freezing it extends its shelf life to 1-2 months past its sell by date. Note that they do not recommend freezing an opened container of yoghurt. However, considering that it keeps for quite a while in the refridgerator as well you may not need to. [This answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/28622/34394) point out a couple of issues with freezing yoghurt, namely that it can get separated - if you put it in a blender that may not be a huge issue, as you kinda mix it together again anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I live in UK and am used to frozen yoghurt as a dessert. To work it needs some sugar and churning.

This article might help.

https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/jul/16/how-to-make-the-perfect-frozen-yoghurt

Here's the recipe..

makes one litre

1l whole-milk plain yoghurt, chilled
100g unrefined caster sugar
100g white caster sugar
1/4 tsp fine salt
1 lemon (optional)

Good luck!

Comment: @MarkWildon I don't see the question asking for later eating as yogurt, merely for use in smoothies. I agree however, not about making frozen yogurt.

Comment: Welcome to the Cooking Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] pages for more information on this site and how to write a good question and/or answer.